# A connected Borel subgroup of the plane

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

[It is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167100/how-do-the-subgroups-of-mathbb-c-which-are-connected-path-connected-in) that the complex plane $\mathbb C$ contain dense connected (additive) subgroups with dense complement but each dense path-connected subgroup of $\mathbb C$ necessarily coincides with $\mathbb C$.

> **Problem.** Does $(\mathbb C,+)$ contain a proper dense connected subgroup, which is a Borel subset of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Lovely question Taras!

Comment: Can you show there is no connected dense proper $G_\delta$-subgroup of the plane?

Comment: @David Each $G_\delta$-subgroup $G$ is Polish and hence is closed in the plane. If it is dense, then $G$ coincides with the plane. In this argument we do not use the connectedness of $G$.